# Cannot read environment variable in Python on Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-2.7, environment-variables, celery

I have set up an environment variable which I execute locally using a `.sh` file:

```
.sh file:
#!/bin/sh
echo "environment variables"
export BROKER="amqp://admin:password@11.11.11.11:4672//"
```

Locally inside a **virtual environment** I can now read this in Python using:

```
BROKER = os.environ['BROKER']
```

However, on my production server (Ubuntu). I run the same file `chmod +x name_of_file.sh` and  `source settings.sh` and can see the variable using `printenv`, but Python gives the error **KeyError: 'BROKER'** Why?

This only happens on my production machine despite the fact I can see the variable using `printenv`. Note my production machines does not use virtualenv.

If I run the python shell on Ubuntu and do `os.environ['BROKER']` it prints out the correct value. So I have not idea what the app file does not find it.

This is the task that gets run which cannot find the variable (supervisor task)

```
[program:celery]
directory = /srv/app_test/
command=celery -A tasks worker -l info
stdout_logfile = /var/log/celeryd_.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=5
stopwaitsecs = 600
killasgroup=true
priority=998
user=ubuntu
```

Celery Config (which does not find the variable when executed under supervisor:

```
from kombu import Exchange, Queue
import os

# Celery Settings

BROKER = os.environ['BROKER']
```

When I restart supervisor it gives the key error.

Comment: The error you got indicates you're doing `os.environ['BROKER_URL']`, and not `os.environ['BROKER']`.

Comment: Because the variable you defined is called `BROKER`, and not `BROKER_URL`?

Comment: Sorry thats a typo in OP, I will update, thats not the issue.

Comment: Just to check: how are you invoking the command on your production server (the two big things that come to mind are A) sudo frequently is configured to remove all env variables, and B) running behind WSGI or something will need to go through other steps to get the envs into that space

Comment: What is "the app file"? Your question is missing a lot of information. Post some code that will reproduce the problem.

Comment: and to rule out your app doing something, if you have a simple program "import os; print os.environ['BROKER']", does that work on your production server?

Comment: I haven't touched celery in many moons, but a quick review of http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html suggests you want to set environment varaibles for celery in /etc/default/celeryd

Comment: @Foon There is no issue with the settings files (I don't think). For some reason on production (ubuntu) when run under supervisor the vars cannot be found in the celery settings file. Locally just running the celery task everything works fine. Is it the user supervisor runs under? i.e. Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The environment variables from your shell will **not** be visible within supervisor tasks.

You need to use the `environment` setting in your supervisor config:

```
[program:celery]
...
environment=BROKER="amqp://admin:password@11.11.11.11:4672//"
```

This requires [supervisor 3.0+.](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html)

Comment: The only different between local and production is supervisor, so I guess this is the issue. How can I get supervisor task to see my envs?

Comment: This is mislleading or I'm reading it wrong: "Subprocesses will inherit the environment of the shell used to start the supervisord program." http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#subprocess-environment

Comment: They inherit the environment given on startup to `supervisord` by the parent process that starts `supervisord`. Who said your shell environment variables are the ones given to `supervisord` on startup?

Comment: I see, anyway I can make it do this? If not, does not matter I understand now.

Comment: Yes you "can" do but then you'd have to supervise supervisord yourself after each server reboot and so on. Just write the variable in the config file, it is the easiest way.

Comment: Thanks, that was a big help.